# Quotient group of $\mathbb{C^*}$ by $n$th roots of unity

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, group-homomorphism, roots-of-unity, quotient-group

I need to find image and kernel of the following homomorphism of groups ($\mathbb{C^*}$ is multiplicative group of complex numbers) $ f: \mathbb{C^*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C^*}$ given by $f(z)=z^n$. I found that $\ker{f} = \{n\text{th roots of unity}\}$. I know that by the homomorphism theorem ${\rm im}\, f\simeq \mathbb{C^*}/\ker{f} $.

I can't find this quotient group. Coset of a given complex number $z \in \mathbb{C^*}$ is (if I'm not wrong) the set of all the nth roots of the complex number $z^n$, but what is the quotient group consisting of all such cosets then (and hence what is the image of the mentioned homomorphism)?

Comment: The map $f$ is surjective. Try thinking in polar coordinates.

Comment: Doesn't the map hit $\mathbb C^\times$ again? :)

Comment: Is it correct that image is isomorphic to $C^*$?

Comment: The image isn't merely isomorphic to ${\bf C}^{\times}$; it *is* ${\bf C}^{\times}$.

Comment: Also $z\to z^{1/n}$ is well-defined, continuous, analytic, and it is a group isomorphism from $\Bbb{C}^*$ to $\Bbb{C}^*/ \mu_n$